Path existence between local maxima
Let $f:\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function and let $M=\{x_1,\dots x_K\}$ be the set of its local maxima. I am trying to determine if there is a way to find out if there exists a 'significant' path between $f(x_i)$ and $f(x_j)$ for $x_i,x_j\in M$ along the graph of $f$ on $\mathbb{S}^2$.
Specifically, a path $P\subset \Gamma(f)$ is significant if for any point $p\in P$ we have $f(p)>c$ where $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is just some fixed constant determining the significance level and $f(x_i)>c$ for all $x_i\in M$.
This appears to be equivalent to finding the connected components of $\Gamma(f|_{A})$ where $A:=\{x\in\mathbb{S}^2|f(x)>c\}$ is the set of significant points.
So far my approach has been one of brute force where I evaluate $f$ on a grid over $\mathbb{S}^2$, remove all the squares that evaluate to below $c$ and by visual inspection determine the paths that exist. This is obviously far from ideal and so I was hoping someone knows of some result about path-connected spaces or connected components that could help to automate this.
